# Boton reiniciare conteo temporizador JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

estoy realizando un temporizador en JavaScript y quiero programar el botón Reinicio que me guarde el valor ingresado en los input ejemplo: 
Horas=0, Minutos=20, segundos=0
Cuando le de en reiniciar el conteo empiece desde los 00:20:00, así sucesivamente

Muchas gracias

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#abierto").click(function(){

    $("#login form").fadeToggle(500);
    $(this).toggleClass("cerrado");
  });
});

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

  var form= document.getElementById("form");
  var btn_iniciar=document.getElementById("btn-iniciar");
  
   var h=document.getElementById("h");
    var m=document.getElementById("m");
    var s= document.getElementById("s");
   
    var amarillo= document.getElementById("ama");
    var segundo = document.getElementById("seg");
    var interval;

    var Horas = document.getElementById("Horas");
    var Minutos = document.getElementById("Minutos");
    var Segundos = document.getElementById("Segundos");

   var btnMenu = document.getElementById("btn-menu");
   var nav = document.getElementById("nav");

   btnMenu.addEventListener("click",function(){
      nav.classList.toggle("mostrar");
   });

   btn_iniciar.addEventListener("click",function(){

      nav.classList.toggle("mostrar");
   });

       
/*----------Accion botones Pausar, Reiniciar-------*/
function inicio () {
  control = setInterval(contador_regresivo,10);
 // document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("parar").disabled = false;
 // document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
 // document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = false;
}
function parar () {
  clearInterval(interval);
  document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = false;
}

function reinicio () {
 /*location.reload();*/
 h=document.getElementById("h");
  m=document.getElementById("m");
  s= document.getElementById("s");

  var amarillo= document.getElementById("ama");
  var segundo = document.getElementById("seg");

  contador_regresivo();  
 
}

/*----------FIN-Accion botones Pausar, Reiniciar-------*/


    function contador_regresivo()
    {

       h=parseInt(h.value);
        m=parseInt(m.value);
        s=parseInt(s.value);
        
        amarillo=parseInt(amarillo.value);

        segundo=parseInt(segundo.value);
        
         
        interval = setInterval(function(){
          setInter();
            
             innerHTML();

        },1000);
        document.getElementById("parar").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = false;
    }

    function setInter(){
      validarCampo();
     
        if(s > 0 && s <= 60) { 
            s--;
            if(s<10){

              s = "0" + s;

            }
           // Segundos.innerHTML = ":" + s; 
            cambiar();
            
        }
        else if (m > 0 && m <= 60) {
            m--;
           if(m <10){
               m = "0" + m;
            }
           // Minutos.innerHTML = ":" + m; 
            s = 59;
            
            cambiar();
            
        }
        else if (h > 0) {
            h--;
            if(h<10){
              h= "0" + h;
              }
           // Horas.innerHTML = h; 
            m = 59;
            s = 59;
          
            cambiar();
           
        }                            
       /* else {
            h = 0;
            m = 0;
            s = 0;                           
            clearInterval(interval);
          
            cambiar();
            
            
        } */

    }
    function innerHTML(){

        Horas.innerHTML= h;
        Minutos.innerHTML = ":" + m;
        Segundos.innerHTML = ":" + s;
    }
    function cambiar(){
    
       if(h>0 || m>0 || s>0){

        document.body.style.backgroundColor="green";
       }
       if(h==0 && m<amarillo && s>=0 || s<segundo){

        document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
       }    
      if(h==00 && m ==00 && s==00){
         document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";   

         audioLoop();
      }

     
    }


    //---------------VALIDAR---NUMEROS-------------------------------------------

    //Validar solo numeros input
    function validar(e) {
        tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (tecla==8) return true;
        patron = /\d/;
        te = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
        return patron.test(te);
    } 

    //focus al ingresar un numero
    function contar(obj,destino) {
      if (obj.value.length==obj.maxLength) destino.focus();
    }

/*---------------------Audio-----------------------------------------------------*/

    var audio=document.getElementById("musica");
    
    

    function audioLoop(){
      

      audio.autoplay=true;
      audio.load();

    }

function validarCampo(){

  if ( isNaN(h) || isNaN(m) || isNaN(s) ){

    alert("ingrese un número válido");

    location.reload();
  }
}

/*-------------FunCION--Boton--Continuar-------------*/

function Continuar()
    {

       /* h=parseInt(h.value);
        m=parseInt(m.value);
        s=parseInt(s.value);
        
        amarillo=parseInt(amarillo.value);

        segundo=parseInt(segundo.value);*/
        
         
       interval = setInterval(function(){
          setInter();
            
             innerHTML();
          
        },1000);
        document.getElementById("parar").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
    }
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-image: url(../img/arbol.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;

    
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
   background-color:#edf5ff;
}
h2, .icon-menu{
    margin: 5px;
}
.header .contenedor{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.icon-menu{
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:#204862;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-left: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.mostrar{
    left: 0;
}
.ocultar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.menu{
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}











.reloj{
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    font-size: 112px;
    font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
    color: black;
}




#ama,  #seg {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*#demo{
    text-align:  center;
    color:black;
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10.5em;
    /*border: 1px solid #aaa;
}*/

/* Set a style for all buttons */
.btn-iniciar {
    width: auto;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #204862;
}

.login{
    background-color: #204862;
    color: white;
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20%;
}

.login:hover{
    background: white;
    color: #204862;
}


/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #204862;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
    position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
    padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* Black w/ opacity */
    padding-top: 60px;
}



input{
    
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;

}

/*Boton Stop Accion*/
.boton{
    background-color: #204862;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.boton:hover{
    background: white;
    color: #204862;
}
/* The Close Button (x) */


.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
    -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
    animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

footer{
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 3px 0px;
  color: #19232f;

}

.copy{
  
  text-align: center;

}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}
    
@keyframes animatezoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)}
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */

@media (min-width:120px ) {

/* Full-width input fields */
#h, #m, #s {
    width: 26%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 94%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */

}
    #digitos{
    margin: 150px auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
}

    .reloj {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
    color: black;
   

        }

    h2{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
        color:black;
    }

.close{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: -15px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
    
}


@media (min-width: 320px ) {


/* Full-width input fields */
#h, #m, #s {
    width: 22%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 94%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */

}
    #digitos{
    margin: 150px auto;
    width: 540px;
    height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
}
    .reloj {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
    color: black;
        
    }
    h2{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
        color:black;
    }
    .close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
    
}

@media(min-width:480px){

/* Full-width input fields */
#h, #m, #s {
    width: 12%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 94%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */

}

    #digitos{
    margin: 150px auto;
    width: 540px;
    height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
}
    .reloj  {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
    color: black;
        
    }
    h2{
         text-align: center;
        font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
        color: black;
    }

    .close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
}
@media(min-width:768px) {

    /* Full-width input fields */
#h, #m, #s {
    width: 12%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    /* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 60%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */

}

    #digitos{
    margin: 150px auto;
    width: 540px;
    height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
}

    .reloj  {
    float: left;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
    color: black;
        
    }

    h2{
         text-align: center;
        font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
        color: black;
    }

    .close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
}

@media(min-width:1024px) {

/* Full-width input fields */
#h, #m, #s {
    width: 12%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 60%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */

}
   
.nav{
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}
.menu{
    display: flex;
}

.icon-menu{
    display: none;
}

#digitos{
    margin: 250px auto;
    width: 890px;
    height: 215px;
    text-align: center;
}

.reloj {
    
    float: left;
    font-size: 185px;
    font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
    color: black;
    /*border: 1px solid #aaa;*/
}
h2{
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px ;
    margin-left:2px;
    color: black;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Temporizador</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prueba.css">
<!--Icono Menu-->
<link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/CHkJoswBZU8cC99VGePWnS/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<body>
<!--<h1 id="demo">00:00:00</h1>-->
<header class="header">
 <div class="contenedor">
 <h2>Temporizador</h2>
  <span class="icon-menu" id="btn-menu"></span>
  <nav class="nav" id="nav">
   <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__link">
     <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:98%;" class="login">Menú</button>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__link">
     <input type="button" class="boton" id="parar" value="Pausar" onclick="parar();" style="width:98%;" disabled>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__link">
     <input type="button" class="boton" id="continuar" value="Continuar" onclick="Continuar()" style="width:98%;" disabled>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__link">
     <input type="button" class="boton" id="reinicio" value="Reiniciar" onclick="reinicio();" style="width:98%;" disabled>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</header>







<div id="id01" class="modal">
  
  <form onkeypress="return validar(event)" class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
    <div class="imgcontainer"> 
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      <!--<img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">-->
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="h" id="h" class="horas" onkeyup="contar(this,s)" value="0" placeholder="Hora" />
 <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="m" id="m" class="minutos" onkeyup="contar(this,h)" value="0" placeholder="Min" >
 <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="s" id="s" class="segundos" onkeyup="contar(this,m)" value="0" placeholder="Seg" autofocus="" >
 <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="ama" id="ama" placeholder="Minutos Color Amarillo"  onkeyup="contar(this,s)" >
 <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="seg" id="seg" placeholder="Segundos Color Amarillo"  onkeyup="contar(this,s)">
        
      <input type="button" onclick="contador_regresivo(),document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="btn-iniciar" id="btn-iniciar" value="Iniciar" /> 
     <audio src="Alerta.mp3" loop id="musica"></audio>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="digitos">
 <div class="reloj" id="Horas">00</div>
 <div class="reloj" id="Minutos">:00</div>
 <div class="reloj" id="Segundos">:00</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prueba.js"></script>
<footer><p class="copy">&copy; Informática USS De la Patagonia - Todos los derechos </p></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cual es el error? que te esta dando problemas?

Comment: estoy realizando un temporizador y quiero hacer el botón de reinicio del contador, al momento de ingresar los valores, me reinicia pero se acelera demasiado el contador y no se en que parte estaré fallando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema esta en que tomas los valores ya asignados, los cuales estos van disminuyendo y al tomar nuevamente los valores con `h=parseInt(h.value);` estos ya no corresponden al elemento sino a la variable `h`,`m`,`s`, etc.; Entonces esto te reproduce el error `NAN` para evitar esto tendrás que volver a tomar los valores desde el `input` y tu función quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
function reinicio (){
  //...
  h=document.getElementById("h");
  m=document.getElementById("m");
  s= document.getElementById("s");
  //...
  clearInterval(interval);
  //ahora llamamos al contador regresivo
  contador_regresivo();
}
```

Comment: lo realice de esa manera y me toma los valores, pero hay algo que acelera demasiado el contador al darle el botón Reiniciar y mientras mas veces se presiona mas se acelera el contador.

Comment: @RodrigoVillarroelSoto tienes que limpiar la variable `interval`, ve la modificación que he hecho

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)